# Which of the combination artifacts can be used together?

Tags: heroes-of-might-and-magic-3

The various combination artifacts each involve some number of individual artifacts; to equip a combined artifact, the slots for the individual artifacts must be available. In some cases equipping multiple combos becomes impossible. In other cases, such as with the Statue of Legion, there's little difficulty in equipping at least one more combo.

Which combination artifacts can be equipped at the same time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I will list the equipment slots used by each combination weapon, from [this page](http://www.heroesofmightandmagic.com/heroes3sod/combinationartifacts.shtml):

- **Admiral's Hat**: Head, Neck
- **Angelic Alliance**: Body, Feet, Neck, Left Hand, Right Hand, Head
- **Armor of the Damned**: Head, Right Hand, Body, Left Hand
- **Bow of the Sharpshooter**: 3 Accessory slots
- **Cloak of the Undead King**: Neck, Cloak, Feet
- **Cornucopia**: Cloak, 2 Ring slots, 1 Accessory slot
- **Elixir of Life**: 2 Ring slots, 1 Accessory slot
- **Power of the Dragon Father**: Head, Neck, Cloak, Right Hand, Left Hand, 2 Ring slots, Feet, Body
- **Ring of the Magi**: Neck, 1 Ring slot, Cloak
- **Statue of Legion**: All Accessory slots
- **Titan's Thunder**: Head, Body, Right Hand, Left Hand
- **Wizard's Well**: 3 Accessory slots

According to page 31 of [the official manual](http://goo.gl/tymbQ3), there are 2 ring slots, 4 accessory/miscellaneous slots, and 1 of each other kind of artifact slot. So, the sets of combination artifacts that can be worn at the same time are

- Admiral's Hat, Bow of the Sharpshooter, Cornucopia
- Admiral's Hat, Bow of the Sharpshooter, Elixir of Life
- Admiral's Hat, Cornucopia, Wizard's Well
- Admiral's Hat, Elixir of Life, Wizard's Well
- Admiral's Hat, Statue of Legion
- Angelic Alliance, Bow of the Sharpshooter, Cornucopia
- Angelic Alliance, Bow of the Sharpshooter, Elixir of Life
- Angelic Alliance, Cornucopia, Wizard's Well
- Angelic Alliance, Elixir of Life, Wizard's Well
- Angelic Alliance, Statue of Legion
- Armor of the Damned, Bow of the Sharpshooter, Cloak of the Undead King, Elixir of Life
- Armor of the Damned, Bow of the Sharpshooter, Cornucopia
- Armor of the Damned, Bow of the Sharpshooter, Ring of the Magi
- Armor of the Damned, Cloak of the Undead King, Statue of Legion
- Armor of the Damned, Cloak of the Undead King, Wizard's Well
- Armor of the Damned, Cornucopia, Wizard's Well
- Armor of the Damned, Elixir of Life, Wizard's Well
- Armor of the Damned, Ring of the Magi, Statue of Legion
- Armor of the Damned, Ring of the Magi, Wizard's Well
- Bow of the Sharpshooter, Cloak of the Undead King, Elixir of Life, Titan's Thunder
- Bow of the Sharpshooter, Cloak of the Undead King, Ring of the Magi, Titan's Thunder
- Bow of the Sharpshooter, Cornucopia, Titan's Thunder
- Bow of the Sharpshooter, Elixir of Life, Ring of the Magi, Titan's Thunder
- Bow of the Sharpshooter, Power of the Dragon Father
- Cloak of the Undead King, Elixir of Life, Titan's Thunder, Wizard's Well
- Cloak of the Undead King, Statue of Legion, Titan's Thunder
- Cornucopia, Titan's Thunder, Wizard's Well
- Elixir of Life, Ring of the Magi, Wizard's Well
- Power of the Dragon Father, Statue of Legion
- Power of the Dragon Father, Wizard's Well